# MySql DB structure with Overriting group settings and allowing settings

Tags: mysql, database

how are you?
I'm working on a project that contains accounts with mailing list.
The account has 3 packages he can buy. Each package has it's own settings. e.g.: first package the user gets 1 email per day, and in second package he gets 5 emails per day.
Another feature that I want is the opertunity to override some of the package settings. Which means, for one account I'll set daily email limit as 7. 
One more feature I need in this system is email providers. I want the first package to get emails only from first provider, second package from 2 providers and so on.

So I have a problem designing my DB.
I created table emailSubscriptions which has EmailID and name.
I created table accountsGroup which only contains GroupId and name.
I created table accounts which has AccountID, GroupID (foreign key), Email, password and investment. (According to his investment he gets his package).
I've created table accountsSubscriptions which has SUBSCRIPTION ID, AccountID, EmailID and IsActive.
I created table packages which contains PackageID, GroupID, from investment and to investment, and all other package settings e.g. maxEmailsPerDay ....

Of course the end user has. GUI that he can see his settings and edit what he can according to his current package. The admin of the users has GUI too.

Any way, now I got stuck.
I thought about adding to accounts all package columns and then when I want to send emails, I'll take the settings from the group and where ever it's not 0 / empty just override, but the problem is when some settings are 0 / 1, then the column is default 0 and if the groupSettings is 1 for something and I want to turn it off I can't. So this is the first problem
The second problem is with allowed emails subscriptions ... Same problem actually.
I thought about adding to package the allowedEmails, but then it means when ever I send the emails I need to use LIKE operator - and this is not good for runtime.

So I really need you help... Hope you can help me.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The requirements part lacks clarity, I'd say.
But let's go for it anyway.

Let's extract entities from this messy field of things.
Each entity would generally means one table.

Start from Account.

Account has Subscriptions. It is not clear what's the relation here: if it is 1:1 ("account can have only one subscription") - then reference to it is a part of the Account entity, if it is 1:n - then you'll need a special Account-Subscriptions relation table.

Now Subscription - it is defined by SubscriptionType, or Package, so there must be a table that contains these records (these limits and whatever else you want). Account or Account-Subscription table would refer to it to define what subscription(s) the Account have.

Then Providers - they're referred by SubscriptionType/Packages. If there could be more than 1 Provider per Package/SubscriptionType - then you need additional Package-Provider realtion table.

And finally, the Overrides. That's a trickier part because of the weak requirements on it, but as soon as they're overriding the Package paremeters, I suggest to keep the entity structure same to the package.

You may even place it into the same Package table, sorting 'em out by date, or assign them weights, always keeping the default Package record with the lowest weight.
Then, when you create an override, you copy the whole default record except for the overridden fields, and assign it next weight (or current date), and when you query it - group it and get the MAX().

There's no Email entity itself - but you didn't mention it in your requirements sections whatsoever.

So, that's pretty much it: Accounts, Subscriptions, (optional) Account-Subscription, Packages, Providers, (optional) Package-Provider, (optional, may be incorporated into Packages) Overrrides.

Works for you?